# WPF: Reset Colors to use template colors

Tags: wpf

I currently have a listboxitemcontainer, which if selected turns the background blue.

However later I programatically set : Border.Background = new solidcolorbrush(colors.white);

How do I reset the the border background now to use the template colors again? Now when I select the box again, it doesn't turn to the selection color anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
border.ClearValue(Border.BackgroundProperty);
```